# PHP set multi select dropdown

Tags: php, for-loop

I am pulling data from my database to retrieve the multiple options that were selected for a multi-select drop down. I an them trying to reset those values as selected but its only selected one of them.

My array from the database:

```
[data] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [term] => LTA
            [prevention] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [reason] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [process] => Recruitment
                                    [processID] => 4
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [process] => People Management
                                    [processID] => 3
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [process] => Not Applicable
                                    [processID] => 2
                                )

                        )
                )

        )
```

Here is the HTML / PHP I am using to generate the options and try to re-select the options in the array:

```
<select name="prevention" id="prevention" class="form-control dd ff" placeholder="Select 1 or more options" multiple="multiple">
<?php foreach($processes->data as $process){ 
   foreach($recordDetails->data->prevention->reason as $is){
    if((int)$is->processID == (int)$process->processID){
        $isSel = 'selected';    
    }
    else
    {
        $isSel = '';    
    }
   }
   ?>
<option value="<?php echo $process->processID . '" '. $isSel . '>'; ?> <?php echo $process->process; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you have some syntactical weirdness happening in this line `<option value="<?php echo $process->processID . '" '. $isSel . '>'; ?>`

Comment: I changed it to `<option value="<?php echo $process->processID; ?>" <?php echo $isSel; ?>> <?php echo $process->process; ?></option>` as a test and it still only selects one of the 3 options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwritting `$isSel` within the inner loop, so you only every get the value of the last iteration.

Instead initialized the variable outside the inner loop:

```
<select name="prevention" id="prevention" class="form-control dd ff" placeholder="Select 1 or more options" multiple="multiple">
<?php 
    foreach($processes->data as $process):
        $isSel = '';
        foreach($recordDetails->data->prevention->reason as $is):
            if((int)$is->processID == (int)$process->processID){
                $isSel = 'selected';
                break;
            }
        endforeach;
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $process->processID . '" '. $isSel . '>'; ?> <?php echo $process->process; ?></option>
    <?php 
    endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This now only gives me one option of the 5 possible in the select list with none selected